# "Do you want to Open or save" not displaying

Tags: c#, excel, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

My Code:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public ActionResult Export()
    {
        DataTable table = ListToDataTable();

        var rows = table.AsEnumerable().AsQueryable() as IEnumerable<DataRow>;
        var output = CreateXlsStream(rows);
        return File(output, "application/vnd.ms-excel", "Export.xls");
    }
```

"Do you want to Open or save" not displaying. I want to display "Do you want to Open or save" by default after executing this "return File(output, "application/vnd.ms-excel", "Export.xls");' line.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work:

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=Export.xls");
return File(...
```